# $ABCD$ is a square of side-length 2.Let there be a circle inscribed in $ABCD$,find the area of slashed area.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

$ABCD$ is a square of side-length 2,$\overset{\frown}{ABC}$,$\overset{\frown}{ADC}$ are quarter circles of radius 2. Let there be a circle inscribed in $ABCD$. Use calculus to find the area of slashed area.

[image]

I want to calculate the area by calculating the area of the "leaf" minus the other two small areas. However I don't know how to use calculus to find the two small areas.

Another thought is that I see $\overline{AC}$ as x-axis,and $\overline{BD}$ as y-axis, and the problem is that I don't know how to find the equation that bounds the region.

Sorry for my poor English.QQ

Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just do it. Break the region up into small enough parts (and sometimes multiple times) until you can write the equation/integral for each part.

Comment: FWIW This is a tedious calculus / trigonometry exercise. AFAIK there is no "nice" insight that will greatly simplify the work.

Comment: The area of the small circle is $\pi$, from it subtract twice the area of the lune. The area of the lune results in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)#Area), where in your case $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let coordinate axes be the diagonals of the square. Then the origin will be the center of the square. The axes will break the shape into four equal areas. Let's consider part in the first quadrant. The equation of the full circle will be $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The equation of the quarter circle centered at $B$ will be $y=\sqrt{4-(x+\sqrt{2})^2}$. Now let's find the point of intersection of the full circle and quarter circle:

$4-(x+\sqrt{2})^2=1-x^2 \rightarrow 2\sqrt{2}x=1, x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

So the area $$I=4\cdot \left(\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx +\int_\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}^{2-\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{4-(x+\sqrt{2})^2}dx \right)$$